# what is the difference between "fastboot erase data" and "fastboot erase userdata"?

Tags: android, fastboot, miui

emmm
I'm just about to flash my android device and when I check some tutorials, I'm confused:
What do `fastboot erase data` and `fastboot erase userdata` actually do?

It is said that `userdata` means /data + /data/media, is it to say that `fastboot erase data` will keep /data/media and erase all other files under /data?